# How to configure the endpoint in a local instance of dynamodb java aws sdk 2.x?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am very new to DynamoDB and started learning with the Java AWS SDK 1.x. I initialized my local dynamodb endpoint with the following code

```
AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder
                       .standard()
                       .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000","us-west-2"))
                       .build();

DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
```

However now I changed my dependencies to Dynamodb and Java 2.15.52, so the client is initialized as:

```
DynamoDbClient client = DynamoDbClient.builder().build();
```

How can I configure **my local endpoint** with the new `DynamoDbClient`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *translation* to the new version in order to initialize the client of your example would be as follows:

```
DynamoDbClient client = DynamoDbClient.builder()
                        .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                        .endpointOverride(URI.create("http://localhost:8000"))
                        .build();

DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
```

---

**`endpointOverride()`** is inherited from [**`SdkClientBuilder`**](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/client/builder/SdkClientBuilder.html#endpointOverride-java.net.URI-)

> *`endpointOverride(URI endpointOverride)`*
>
> *Configure the endpoint with which the SDK should communicate*.`

**`region()`** is inherited from [**`AwsClientBuilder`**](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/awscore/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#region-software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region-)

> *`region(Region region)`*
>
> *Configure the region with which the SDK should
> communicate.*

---

***More info about upgrading the DynamoDB client [here](https://www.rohannagar.com/2019-02-07/migrating-aws-sdk-version).***